# How to adapt my dataset to Theano?

Tags: python, numpy, theano

I'm trying to use the codes in the book http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/ in my own dataset.

I learned that i need to put my data in a numpy array, and then use in the functions. To do this, I use this code:

```
import pickle
def generateDataset(filesDir):
   x = np.asarray([np.asarray(Image.open(fname)) for fname in filesDir])
   with open('dataset.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
      pickle.dump( x, handle, protocol=2)
```

But when I try to load the .pkl file with cPickle and use in the function, i got this message:

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I search and try many things but don't have sucess. Someone knows how do i use my own dataset in this project or in Theano?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the error message caused by an exception raised in the above code?

Comment: No, is caused when i use the codes in the book.

Comment: Ok, because the error is a result of an ambiguous comparison to a list of booleans, for example ``my_boolean == [True, False]``, or more likely using numpy masking. It does not know how to compare/filter it: should both elements in the array be required to be True or is it sufficient if one of them is True? Hence the tip of using ``a.any()`` (is True if any element is True) or ``a.all()`` (requires all elements to be True).

Comment: Can you provide more information on which book your code is coming from?

Comment: @ThomasFauskanger  http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/ this book. The source code is here https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning

Comment: As far as I can tell there is more than one set of code there? Which part of the book is you referring to? (And which code files are you running?)